# laravel - unable to mark notifications

Tags: laravel

I created a notification that fetch all the latest notification and also mark them as read upon clicking them.

UserNotifications.vue:

```
<template>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown" v-if="notifications.length">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
      <span class="fas fa-bell"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id">
                <a :href="notification.data.link"
                   v-text="notification.data.message"
                   @click="markAsRead(notification)"
                ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</template>

<script>
     export default {
        data() {
            return {notifications: false}
        },
 
        created() {
            axios.get('/profiles/' + window.App.user.name + '/notifications')
                .then(response => this.notifications = response.data);
        },
 
        methods: {
            markAsRead(notification) {
                axios.delete('/profiles/' + window.App.user.name + '/notifications/' + notification.id)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

UserNotificationsController:

```
class UserNotificationsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications;
    }

    public function destroy($user,$notificationId){
        auth()->user()->notifications()->findOrFail($notificationId)->markAsRead();
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
//Get notification for user
Route::get('/profiles/{user}/notifications','UserNotificationsController@index')->name('notification.index');

//Delete notification
Route::delete('/profiles/{user}/notifcations/{notification}','UserNotificationsController@destroy')->name('notifcation.destroy');
```

While getting the unread notifications work but when I clicked on the notifications, it came back with a response error 404 not found. The notification tables has the correct notificationId but yet it could not mark it as read. I don't understand why it could not work.

In the notification table, the read_at column is NULL after clicking the unread notifications. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Does the URL for the request have the correct notification id at the end?

Comment: @Rwd yeap, it says ```DELETE http://forum.test/profiles/Nicholas/notifications/f6d095e2-e342-42a8-a294-0e3187c11dcb 404 (Not found)```. I check my notification table id and it matches the hash value at the URL.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the notification via the user manually with tinker (or a separate route) e.g. `$user->notifications()->findOrFail('f6d095e2-e342-42a8-a294-0e3187c11dcb')`?

Comment: I inspected further down the failed request and it says: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"

Comment: @Rwd Okay I just tested in tinker and yea I can retrieve the results in the notification table.

Comment: I was assuming that the 404 was being caused by the `findOrFail`. On closer inspection, it looks like you have a typo in your `delete` route (`notifcations` instead of `notifications`).

Comment: @Rwd Ah that was it, it was the typo lol. Spent hours trying to find what went wrong. Thanks dude. Anyway, post an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: No worries at all. We've all been there! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a typo in your `delete` route (notifcations).

Updating the delete route should do the trick:

```
Route::delete('/profiles/{user}/notifications/{notification}', 'UserNotificationsController@destroy')->name('notification.destroy');
```